# Sabre web services: Revalidate ticket

Tags: sabre

I'm working on revalidate flow and face with an issue.
The web services flow is the following:

```
1 - CreatePNR
2 - Issue ticket
3 - Change the flight date (cancel and book a new one)
4 - Call revalidate host command EVCR‡REVAL - it works fine.
5 - EndTransaction - returns error ITINERARY REQUIRED TO COMPLETE TRANSACTION
```

I would be grateful for any comments and suggestions.

Comment: Please post your calls/responses. Otherwise its hard to see where it failed. Have you checked that you are allowed to Revalidate the specific carrier (as not all Carriers allow you to do that by yourself)

Comment: @Thomas actually the main call here is EVCR‡REVAL
I expected to see revalidated ticket after that, but in fact the response says OK and the ticket is not changed

revalidation is allowed
ETR REVALIDATION ALLOWED -  YES

Comment: Why dont you use - RevalidateItinRQ? nevertheless its hard to tell what went wrong just by looking at the order of calls. Could be that you forogot to have statefull call to the pnr to really anything in nearly each call you mentioned or inbetween each one.

Comment: Not sure that revalidateRQ is one I need. The Revalidate Itinerary (RevalidateItinRQ) API is used to recheck the availability and price of a specific itinerary option without booking the itinerary. I need revalidate a ticket. Anyway thank you for the comments I will take a look into it. Another strange point here is that the flow I mentioned above works good via Sabre interact, but does not work via WS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue.

I changed revalidation call symbol from EVCR‡REVAL to EVCR¥REVAL

So I changed ‡ to ¥